# Logistic regression cost function returning inconsistant values

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression

I am currently writing a logistic regression function in python 3 using numpy and google colaboratory. While everything else works, my cost function is returning an variety of different values. When graphed it looks like this
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP6Nm.png) .

```
theta = np.zeros((3,1))
def sigmoid(z):
  g = (1 / (1 + np.exp(-z)))
  return g

def costFunction():
  Hx = sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta));
  mul0 = ((-y) * np.log(Hx))
  mul1 = ((1 - y) * np.log(1 - (Hx)))
  J = (1 / m) * np.sum(mul0 - mul1)
  return J
```

X is a 3 column matrix as is y. m is the number of training examples. Full code at https://colab.research.google.com/drive/128biX9f0LywzBKkgkIcjGGcagkZH3fAC

Comment: In the linked file, immediately above "Graphing the Data", there are divide-by-zero and "invalid value" and overflow warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The logistic loss function for labels in {-1, 1} is

```
np.log(1. + np.exp(-y * X.dot(theta)))
```

Its gradient is

```
X.T.dot(-y * sigmoid(- y * X.dot(w))
```

For gradient descent, the inverse of the stepsize should be `norm(X, ord=2) ** 2 / 2`